# What is the converse of add-apt-repository?

Tags: package-management, ppa, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can PPAs be removed after they have been added with the add-apt-repository command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed-after-they-have-been-added-with-the-add-apt-repository-co)

You can a new PPA repository with add-apt-repository. How do you remove an added repository?